# kubernetes annotations being ignored

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, annotations

The following annotations are being ignored by kubernetes. When I describe the ingress they are not showing up and nginx is not using affinity.

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ydos-ingress
  namespace: ydos
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/client-body-buffer-size: 1M
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "YDOS-SESSION-EX"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-client: "on"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-secret: "ydos/wildcard-yellowdog-tech-secret"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-verify-depth: "1"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-tls-pass-certificate-to-upstream: "false"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - service.yellowdog.tech
    secretName: wildcard-yellowdog-tech-secret
  rules:
  - host: service.yellowdog.tech
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /ydos
        backend:
          serviceName: ydos-svc
          servicePort: 80
```

I would expect annotations and events, not the following;

```
$ kubectl describe ingress ydos-ingress -n ydos
Name:             ydos-ingress
Namespace:        ydos
Address:          130.61.9.241
Default backend:  default-http-backend:80 (<none>)
TLS:
  wildcard-yellowdog-tech-secret terminates service.yellowdog.tech
Rules:
  Host                    Path  Backends
  ----                    ----  --------
  service.yellowdog.tech
                          /ydos   ydos-svc:80 (<none>)
Annotations:
Events:  <none>
```

Comment: did you tried to use `kubectl get ingress -n ydos` ?

Comment: seems to be an issue in k8s "looks like older versions of kubectl describe only showed some annotations. fixed in #58529 from github"

to be clear, that only affects display by kubectl, not use of those annotations by any other components